# Connect to azure sql with managed identity python

Tags: python, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database

I have a compute in azure ML that I am using for development. I am trying to connect to an azure sql database with managed identity but unable to do so as it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "active_monitoring/dbtester.py", line 8, in <module>
    err_mart_conn.open_connection(local=False)
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/ourrehman2/code/Users/ourrehman/Sweden_cashflow_forecasting_aml/ml_logic/active_monitoring/db_manager.py", line 47, in open_connection
    self.conn = pyodbc.connect(self.conn_str)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Here is the **user managed identity**:
[image]

and it is linked to my compute as such:
[image]

The user was created on sql side as such:

```
CREATE USER [cluster-xxxxxxxxxx-dev] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'cluster-xxxxxxxxxx-dev'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'cluster-xxxxxxxxxx-dev'
```

Also, **on sql side, we have firewalls but exceptions are made for any azure resource trying to connect. And my compute is on AML and it should be considered azure resource I beleive.**

I have installed sql driver 18 using the following code:

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

I have the following class to **conencto to database**:

```
class DBManager:
    def __init__(self, server : str, database : str, driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'):
        self.server = server
        self.database = database
        self.conn_str = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};Server={server};Database={database};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi"
        self.logging = Logger().getLogger(__name__)
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None
    
    def open_connection(self, local=True):
        if local:
            # open connection to local database
            pass
        else:
            print(self.conn_str)
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect(self.conn_str)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

            try:
                self.logging.info('Verifying the connection...')
                self.cursor.execute("SELECT getdate()")
                _ = self.cursor.fetchone()
                self.logging.info("Conection successfull")
            except Exception as e:
                self.logging.error("Unable to connect: ", str(e))
                raise e


    def execute_query(self, query):
        if query is None:
            self.logging.info('Empty query passed.')
```

The calling code is:

```
from db_manager import DBManager
server = 'myservername' # parametrize this 
database = 'mydatabasename' # parametrize this 

err_mart_conn = DBManager(server, database)
err_mart_conn.open_connection(local=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Azure AD Authentication and set an Admin for SQL server login and then I tried to log in to Azure SQL via SSMS with Azure AD Universal MFA option by setting the silicon database like below:-

[image]

[image]

```sql
CREATE USER  <managed-identity> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

```sql
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER <managed-identity>
```

Added the managed identity to access the SQL DB with the above query :-

[image]

Used below Python code to connect to SQL Server from managed identity and got the same error code as yours like below :-

[image]

Added my Vm’s managed Identity or you can add your cluster’s IP in the allow list of Azure SQL server like below :-

[image]

Now, I logged inside my VM assigned managed identity and ran the python code from the VM and was able to connect to Azure SQL like below :-

[image]

You need to connect to your ML cluster and run this command from the cluster and not outside of it and add the Cluster Public IP in the Azure SQL Networking and assign the cluster managed identity the requried role. refer below :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, While connecting through your ML Cluster verify your connection string like below :-
import pyodbc

```py
    def  init_connection(): 
    return  pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER="
    + "<sqlserver>.database.windows.net,1433"
    + ";DATABASE="
    + "<db_name>"
    +";auth = ActiveDirectoryMsi"
    )
  ``
```

OR

```py
    import pyodbc
    server = '<SQLserver>.database.windows.net,1433'
    database = '<db-name>'
    auth = 'ActiveDirectoryMsi'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=no;Auth='+auth)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Reference :-

[Login timeout expired when using ODBC Driver 17 to connect to MS SQL Server 12.0 via Ubuntu 18.04.1 proxy server (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/62f1f8db-0c4f-4fd5-809c-63d218154f2a/login-timeout-expired-when-using-odbc-driver-17-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-120-via-ubuntu-18041?forum=sqldataaccess)

[[Python] SQL database access with managed identity from Azure Web App / Functions | by Hedi | Medium](https://hedihargam.medium.com/python-sql-database-access-with-managed-identity-from-azure-web-app-functions-14566e5a0f1a)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql

Comment: @SiddheshDesaiHi have tried what you did above. It gives the following error now:

pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Have you faced similar issue?